# Gunicorn Worker Class for GPU Tasks

Tags: python, gunicorn

I'm using Flask with Gunicorn to implement an AI server. The server takes in http requests and calls the AI algorithms (built with `pytorch`). The computation is run on the nvidia GPUs. The driver interface I'm using is `pycuda`. I need some input as to how can I achieve concurrency/parallelism in this case. The machine usually has 8 GPUs or more. And each one can run multiple algorithms.

The specific question is which worker class of Gunicorn (or say Python's concurrency library) might be best suited for this kind of tasks?

I know the common strategies are:

1. If the applicaiton is I/O bounded, choose "pseudo-threads" such as   `gevent`.
2. If the application is CPU bounded, use processes to achieve parallelism due to Python's GIL.
3. If it concerns about memory footprint, use `gthread` or `gevent` in favor of process workers.

The about statements might not be super accurate but I think it works as a genernal guideline.

For GPU tasks, however, I'm not sure if we should treat them just as the CPU-bounded case or do they have something special? Will the GPU computations be affected by the `GIL` if I use `gthreads` instead of processes?

Comment: You should be able to test hat easily on your usecases and code. Nobody will be able to give a more accurate answer without your code, system setup and even Python version.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, that's true. But I just want to have more theories first regarding Python threading and GPU.

Comment: Rule #1 of threading: It never works as in theory. Or as a [picture](https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/2oagj8/multithreaded_programming_theory_and_practice/).

Comment: @JFreebird Any update?

Comment: @Snehal  Used Gunicorn threads